# Returning tables of objects from C++, adopt policy

Tags: lua, luabind

Using luabind, I create a table of objects from C++

```
luabind::object create_table(lua_State *L)
{
  luabind::object result = luabind::newtable(L);
  int index = 1;
  for ( ... ) {
    lua_Object *o = new lua_Object( ... );
    result[ index ++ ] = o;
  }
  return result;
}
```

I register the function as

```
module(L)
[
  def("create_table", &create_table)
]
```

and lua_Object as

```
class_<lua_Object> reg("Object");
reg
  .def(constructor<float,float>())
  ;
module(L) [ reg ];
```

How can I tell luabind to take ownership of the objects stored in the table ( new lua_Object( ... ) )? What would be a work around?

Thanks -

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
result[ index ++ ] = o
```

with

```
result[ index ++ ] = luabind::object(L, o, luabind::adopt(luabind::result));
```

On a side note, don't you have to register `create_table` with `raw(_1)` policy?

Comment: Thanks - I just gave it a try and it works fine. The raw policy is no longer required: http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#raw , just put lua_State * as first parameter and luaBind automatically detects it.